# apt update not working in google cloud

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have an Ubuntu 17.04 (zesty) instance running in GCE.  When I try to do

```
sudo apt update
```

it just hangs, with

```
0% [Connecting to us-east1.gce.archive.ubuntu.com (104.196.174.47)] [Connecting to security.ubuntu.com (91.189.88.
```

it also hangs if I put in explicit pointers to the Ubuntu US servers, for example:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty main restricted
```

and putting in a Mirror command causes a segfault:

```
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt zesty main restricted universe multiverse
```

Any idea how I can get apt working again so that I can patch my server?

Comment: It seems like a networking issue. I'd recommend checking both internal firewall of your VM and GCE firewall to make sure that egress traffic is allowed to the affected repository web server.

Comment: Thanks.  I was able to ping stuff outside my VM, but I was unable to get any other protocol to them (http(s), ssh, ftp).  I was not willing to leave an unpatched server out there, so I build a new one (which works just fine), and trashed the problem child.  I suppose we will never know the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, in order to connect to an outbound service you need to have an external IP address **and** allow the traffic in your VPC network by adding a firewall rule.

Here's the CLI command to add an external IP address - replace INSTANCE_NAME with your instance name and ZONE with the instance zone:

```
gcloud compute instances add-access-config INSTANCE_NAME --zone=ZONE
```

If that still doesn't work here's how you add a firewall to allow all traffic - replace NETWORK with your network:

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow-all --network=NETWORK --allow=all
```

If this solves your problem I highly recommend tightening up the access to your VPC network.